# Command not found error in c shell

Tags: linux, csh

I have the following script:

```
set blah1 = 12743
set sid1 = `"ps -p $blah1 -o sid"`
echo "$sid1"
```

What I expect that will happen is that $blah1 will be replaced with it's value and then the command will be executed with it's value placed in sid1. Instead, I'm getting an error:

```
ps -p 12743 -o sid: command not found.
```

What's my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Of note: [***this***](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [***this***](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) (first published over a quarter century ago!) and even [***this***](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/). While it doesn't necessarily hurt to *know* how to script in csh, actually *doing* it may harm your pets.

Comment: My pets are already harmed. Sometimes you have to maintain something written in a "bad" language.

Comment: [csh command substitution site:unix.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+command+substitution+site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is the double quotes.

The `ps` command takes a set of arguments. Those arguments are whitespace-separated in the string within the backquotes. By using double quotes, you eliminate the whitespace separation, and you ask the shell to launch a command that looks like the entire quoted string.

Try:

```
set sid1 = `ps -p "$blah1" -o sid`
```

and see if you fare any better.

By way of example, try comparing the output of `ls -a` at your shell prompt with the output of `"ls -a"`.

```
1% ls -a
.       ..
2% "ls -a"
ls -a: Command not found.
```

N.B. Same things happens with other shells than csh (i.e. POSIX, Bash, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You use the quotation marks:

```
a b c d e
```

... means: Run the program named `a`; the parameters are `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`.

```
"a b c d e"
```

... means: Run the program named `a b c d e` (with space characters in the file name); no parameters.

The error message indicates that the shell is searching for an executable file named `ps -p 12743 -o sid`.